# Cooldown handler -discord.js - Set it to GuildID specific cooldown instead of wide

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this cooldown handler for my discord bot, it works just as I want but it applies cooldown on all servers instead of the one where user used the command. Is it possible to modify it and how would i do that? I need a way to somehow do that make those cooldown guild specific instead of guild-wide cooldown

````
const { prefix: defaultPrefix } = require("../../config");
const prefixSchema = require("../../models/prefixSchema");

const languageSchema = require('../../models/languageSchema');
const { translations } = require("../../lang.json");

const discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {

  if (message.channel.type == 'dm') return;

  let prefix;
  let dbPrefix = await prefixSchema.findOne({ guildID: message.guild.id });

  if (dbPrefix) {
    prefix = dbPrefix.prefix;
  } else {
    prefix = defaultPrefix;
  }
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const command =
    client.commands.get(cmd) ||
    client.commands.find((a) => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));

  const jezyk = await languageSchema.findOne({
    guildID: message.guild.id,
  })

  const lang = jezyk.language

  if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
    cooldowns.set(command.name, new discord.Collection());
  }

  const current_time = Date.now();
  const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
  const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

  if (time_stamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

    if (current_time < expiration_time) {
      //const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;
      const time_left = new Date(expiration_time - current_time).toISOString().substr(11, 8)

      const bicon = client.user.displayAvatarURL();
      const cooldown_command = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`${translations.ERROR_OCCUR[lang]}`, client.user.avatarURL())
        .setDescription(`${translations.TIMEOUT_DESCRIPTION_1[lang]} **${time_left}** ${translations.TIMEOUT_DESCRIPTION_2[lang]} **${command.name}**!`)
        .setColor(`#FF6347`)
        .setFooter(`${translations.DATE[lang]}`)
        .setTimestamp();
      return message.channel.send(cooldown_command);
    }
  }

  time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
  setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);

  try {
    if (command) command.execute(message, args, client);
  } catch (err) {
    message.reply("wystąpił błąd krytyczny!");
    console.log(err);
  }
};```
````

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: It applies cooldown on ALL discord servers. I need it to apply cooldown for someone on ONE server that he used the command